# Simple Linq to XML question

Tags: xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Given the XML below..

and given that I have two variable 'Idnt' and 'Xref' which will store the # ID .. How do I get those values ?

I want

```
var Idnt = 5169452
and
var xref = 5169452




 <ecf:EntityPerson xmlns:ecf="xx">
  <nc:PersonName xmlns:nc="xx">
    <nc:PersonGivenName>JAMES</nc:PersonGivenName>
    <nc:PersonMiddleName>TIBERIUS</nc:PersonMiddleName>
    <nc:PersonSurName>KIRK</nc:PersonSurName>
  </nc:PersonName>
  <nc:PersonOtherIdentification xmlns:nc="xx">
    <nc:IdentificationID>5169452</nc:IdentificationID>
    <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>IDNT</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
  </nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
  <nc:PersonOtherIdentification xmlns:nc="xx">
    <nc:IdentificationID>5169452</nc:IdentificationID>
    <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>XREF</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
  </nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
</ecf:EntityPerson>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XNamespace ns = "xx";

var doc = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);
int idnt =
    int.Parse(
        doc.Descendants(ns + "PersonOtherIdentification")
        .Where(e => e.Element(ns + "IdentificationCategoryText").Value == "IDNT")
        .Single().Element(ns + "IdentificationID").Value);

Console.WriteLine(idnt);
```